# Installing Zend2 Skeleton Project

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2

I see that a lot of people tend to have problems with 403 when setting up zend2 for the first time.

I understand you need to add the virtual host to the httpd.conf file.

My problem is after running `composer install` inside the project folder when I go to `localhost/skel` it does not load the index file. It just shows me all the directories and files in the browser.

Then when I add `localhost/skel/public` to the url I get this error in the page,

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/skel/module/Application/config/module.config.php on line 78
```

So then when I add the config to the httpd.hosts file it gives me a 403 to the page and I cannot access the public folder anymore as well.

```
/Applications/AMPPS/www/skel/public
```

Here is httpd.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName equilibrium-index.local
 DocumentRoot /Applications/AMPPS/www/skel/public
 SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "dev"
 <Directory /Applications/AMPPS/www/skel/public>
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

This is the reference from the error

```
  'Application\Controller\Index' => Controller\IndexController::class
),
```

And that whole section

```
'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => Controller\IndexController::class
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: show config pleas module/Application/config/module.config.php this file

Comment: I added the link in reference then I added that whole block of arrays where the error is coming from

Comment: I think I might know what the problem is but I don't know how to fix it. So if my install is in the root Applications and I am logged in as a user 'wuno' maybe it not allowing my user wuno access to the site? Could this truly be a permissions problem? This is a fresh install so I do not see why it would be from a syntax error.

Comment: what version of php you use?

Comment: ok I got it to work.. I changed the config and now the index page loads. But it has the syntax error in it... php version 5.5.30

Comment: Yet again you were right.. I changed my php version to 5.6 and it loads now.

Comment: strangly why zf2 does't work on php5.5

Comment: ya it is weird.. and I still do not have it working. The way my host file is set now it is loading localhost as the index page from zend. If I type in localhost/skel now I get the zend 404 page. And any site I have in my sites folder gives me 404 lol. I am not off to a good start with zend 2 lol

Comment: What you use Linux or Windows, 404 error if zf dont find controller class and not loaded him, this error repeat if you don't have right permision or folder name.

Comment: Please check the installation instructions here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/ref/installation.html#apache-setup, particularly the "if you are using Apache 2.4 or above" part. I'm guessing you are, so your vhost needs to be modified.